# Difficulties on remove/resize an LV. [device busy]

Tags: lvm

i'm facing difficulties removing a logical volume from my server on SLES11SP3.
Checked online for help, tried many things with no success, thus i ask the experts.

```
# lvscan
├─vg-lv_a (dm-22)    253:22   0   50G  0

# lsblk
ACTIVE            '/dev/vg/lv_a' [50.00 GiB] inherit

# lvremove /dev/mapper/vg-lv_a
Do you really want to remove active logical volume lv_a? [y/n]: y
device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
Unable to deactivate vg-lv_a (253:22)
Unable to deactivate logical volume "lv_a"
 
# lvchange -an /dev/mapper/vg-lv_a
device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy
Unable to deactivate vg-lv_a (253:22)

# dmsetup remove vg-lv_a
device-mapper: remove ioctl on vg-lv_a failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

No mountpoints on LV.

Other checks:

```
# dmsetup info -c | grep lv_a
vg-lv_a    253  22 L--w    1    4      0 LVM-LroqO1V0...

# lsof | grep "253,22"
empty
```

Cannot obtain the evdence of the process that takes the LV busy, if any.
Any hints, ideas how to address this?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add code blocks (with tripe backticks). I tried to edit it for you, but I can't tell which blocks go together.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Probably not your case, but what does `losetup --list` show? Using LV's as loop devices, doesn't show up in `lsof`, if I recall correctly.

Comment: used losetup -a , empty output

Comment: SP3 is past end of support; you should be on SP4 already.

Comment: Can you post the output of `lvs`?

Comment: This for the specific LV  `lv_a    vg     -wi-ao---  50.00g`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and couldn't find any process or mount that was holding the device hostage. It did seem however that in my `tmux` session in one of the windows I had the mounting folder opened. Navigating to a different folder in all the open panes solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you really know what you are doing, you can just remove it via dmsetup. But it's really interesting what is using that LV.

Comment: tried with dmsetup remove -f vg-lv_a , but it fails as well [Device or resource busy, command failed]

Comment: To track, was able to resize that incriminated volume after a reboot of the server